# Exclude all files in any directory named node_module with gulp

Tags: gulp

I have a directory structure with nested `node_module` directories.

```
root
    node_modules
    file.txt
    test
        node_modules
        file.txt
```

I want to generate:

```
root
    file.txt
    test
        file.txt
```

The glob pattern is escaping me.

I'm using

```
gulp.src(['**/*', '!(**/*/node_modules)'])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following excludes all files in all `node_modules` folders:

```
gulp.src(['**/*', '!**/node_modules/**'])
```

However this still includes the `node_modules` folders themselves. We need to exclude those seperately:

```
gulp.src(['**/*', '!**/node_modules/**', '!**/node_modules'])
```

Finally we can shorten the above by using brace expansion:

```
gulp.src(['**/*', '!**/node_modules{,/**}'])
```

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Nice use of `{,/**}`